# View when a known Bluetooth device was last connected

Tags: bluetooth, logging, geolocation, android-wear

I somehow managed to loose my LG G Watch, and it has now been about 2 weeks :/

Around the time that I lost it, I was doing some traveling, so I am trying to figure out where exactly me device might be.

To do that, I have though about using my device to figure out when the last connection happened, and then using Google's Location History to determine my approximate location.

How can I figure out when a bluetooth device was last connected, or when Android wear last sunc?

Any and all help is greatly  appreciated.